# Container Hierarchy. CreateChildContainer working incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

Why container trying to resolve a parent instance?

```
container.RegisterType<ICurrentRightholder, CurrentRightholder>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
var container = _container.CreateChildContainer();
container.RegisterType<ICurrentRightholder>(new InjectionFactory(c => new BusCurrentRightholder(message.UserId, () => c.Resolve<ISecurityDbContext>())));
var cr = container.Resolve<ICurrentRightholder>();
```

I got error:
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "....ICurrentRightholder", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

But in console application I tried it and it working.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ICurrentRightholder>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => new BusCurrentRightholder(new Guid("8318a7c5-c783-4e0c-b9de-5272e233861c"), () => c.Resolve<ISecurityDbContext>())));
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        child.RegisterType<ICurrentRightholder>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => new BusCurrentRightholder(new Guid("9318a7c5-c783-4e0c-b9de-5272e233861c"), () => c.Resolve<ISecurityDbContext>())));
        var cr = child.Resolve<ICurrentRightholder>();
```

Comment: How are you executing the code that you said is not working? Is it running in an asp.net mvc app or running inside a unit test project? Can you update your question with more details?

Comment: running in an asp.net mvc app

Comment: What does your CurrentRightholder constructor looks like? any overloads exists for that constructor?

Comment: First constructor: public CurrentRightholder(ICurrentUser currentUser, Func<ISecurityDbContext> contextFactory)    Second - public CurrentRightholder(Guid id, Func<ISecurityDbContext> contextFactory)